# internet explorer in Windows 7 shuts down when open and will not let operation

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

internet explorer in Windows 7 shuts down when open and will not let operation  I have narrowed it down to the advanced feature in internet setting of "enable third party browser extensions".  If this feature is enabled then explorer 8 in windows 7 shuts down and will not operation.

Once you turn off this feature the browser works but will not let you click on specific things in the website or view videos in a website etc.

How do I get rid of this problem.

Comment: If you _prefer to use_ Internet Explorer, then I recommend updating to the [Internet Explorer 9 Beta](http://windows.microsoft.com/ie9). It has improved web standards, HTML5, speed, and security.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try updating/reinstalling Flash and/or Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through the aforementioned 3rd party browser extensions and disable them one-by-one (via Tools|Internet Options|Programs|Manage Add-ons), restarting after each change, until you determine which one is causing the problem.